# PLSQL Proc to run sql script and save output to windows directory in excel or csv format

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have requirement to run custom oracle sql script and save output as csv/excel to windows directory where we have pl/sql is installed .

script has around 30 columns .for sample below query can be used

```
SELECT emp_idno,emp_fname,emp_lname,emp_dept FROM emp_details
```

sample data

```
emp_idno    emp_fname   emp_lname   emp_dept
839139      Maria       Foster      57
127323      Michale     Robbin      57
843795      Enric       Dosio       57
847674      Kuleswar    Sitaraman   57
555935      Alex        Manuel      57
```

the output of the file should be saved to windows D:/Output/file.xlsx

Is there a way I can make this exportable into a CSV or Excel format from pl/sql block? or can we have some kind of automated in pl/sql to do this ? Can anyone provide me with some guidance here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **SQL** script, why would you then involve a **PL/SQL** procedure into it?

From my point of view:

- SQL script should contain the *full* code which "exports" data

  - in other words, it utilizes the SQL*Plus `spool` command, result will be a CSV file
  - there are different `set` options you could/should use to make the output *pretty*
- create an operating system batch file (on MS Windows, that's the .BAT file); it should call the `sqlplus` executable and run your SQL file
- use your operating system's scheduling tool; on MS Windows, it is `Task Scheduler`

  - schedule execution of the BAT file (e.g. every day at 05:00)

That's all; when you come to work, file will be ready for further processing.